# Issues using shareplum to access sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to access a sharepoint site using Shareplum.

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365

authcookie = Office365('https://my.sharepoint.com', username='username@domain.edu', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/.../_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx', authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('list items')
data = sp_list.GetListItems('All Items', rowlimit=200)
```

However, I get the following error when I try to run this script.

```
Exception: ('ERROR:', 500, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Exception of type \'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException\' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">\r\n    List does not exist.\r\n    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.\r\n    </errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>')
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that the specified list does not exist. From the site url, i understand you want to retrieval list items from personal site (onedrive). Please take a reference of below code, it works well here:

```html
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
from config import config

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']

authcookie = Office365('https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com', username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
site = Site('https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/aaa_xxx_onmicrosoft_com',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('Documents')
data = sp_list.GetListItems('All',row_limit=10)

print(data)
```

Comment: GetListItems('All',row_limit=10) it would be like this GetListItems('All Documents',row_limit=10)